# Sendgrid inbound parse webhook is called twice

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm returning a 200 code from my webhook with this code.

```
  response.writeHead(200, { Connection: 'close', Location: '/' });
  return response.end();
```

For some reason, my webhook is called twice per incoming email. Any idea why?

My webhook is a firebase HTTP function.